# How to check whether the current user has been removed from the shared workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, share

I have a shared document which runs various commands upon close. This includes saving normally (if document is still shared) and saving as shared (if document was unshared).

The problem arises when a person left the document open for a while then close it. The document automatically overrides the current document (if the document was made unshared, or it gives the option to overide when the .save command runs) and the data which was entered meanwhile is potentially lost.

How do I check if the user is removed from the document, so that the saving section can be skipped if that's the case?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count     
        If Sheets(i).ProtectContents = False Then
            Call Protect_Sheets 'Protects all the sheets
        End If
    Next i

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = False Then
        Call Protect_Workbook 'Protects the workbook
    End If

    If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing = False Then
        Call SaveAsShared 'Saves the workbook as shared (overrides)
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Save 'Only saves as normal when the document was shared upon close (but defaults the current document name (which will override when no attention is paid))
    End If

End Sub
```

If possible, I want another 'If' (just before calling the SaveAsShared function), which terminates the Sub when the user has been removed from the workbook.
Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Lou

Comment: If the user has been removed from the document, would they know they have been removed, would their temp version of the document know?

Comment: How do you check whether the temp version is still connected to the document? I am not sure what happens to the document when you are kicked from it... Also, I will insert a message box to tell them they have been removed if that's the case. (BTW Thank you very much for looking at this)

Comment: If you can tell when they have been disconnected what if you saved a local version somewhere so that their changes aren't lost if they need to add them to the main document, additionally all the code on exit can run as normal because when it does workbook.save it will just save over the version created when they got removed

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However this won't work because the document is constantly changing (why duplicates won't work). I just need something to help me differentiate between a project where a person who has been kicked and a project where the person hasn't been kicked, so the Sub is terminated when its detected.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a temporary fix. I use a command (ShowConflictHistory) which returns an error when you have been kicked out of the document, then I use error handling techniques to save a unique copy;

```
On Error GoTo Errhandler:
If ActiveWorkbook.ShowConflictHistory = False Or True Then 'This returns Err 1004 if the person has been kicked from the workbook, so it can be handled accordingly in ErrHandler.
End If

Continue1: 
On Error Resume Next

'''''''''
'Main code section
'''''''''

Exit Sub

Errhandler:

Select Case Err
     Case 1004: 'The error which results if you've been kicked out of the document.
        Call SaveCopyOfShared
        Exit Sub    
     Case Else:
        GoTo Continue1:
End Select

End Sub
```

If someone comes up with a more conventional solution. Please let me know.

Comment: So I thought this was working but it actually fails even if the workbook is shared.