# Prevent saving a copy of a shared workbook if user was disconnected

Tags: vba, excel

Before we start: Please don't question why I'm Using them or complain about shared workbooks because they break and crash and be come corrupted etc unfortunately it is a necessity for the situation.

I have resolved almost all the issues with them and posted most of the code to accomplish this on Stack Exchange. I'm up to over 10 months of them running smoothly with no issues and about 100 users using them daily making thousands of changes.

I am now down to one final problem of preventing a user saving a copy of the workbook or overwriting a workbook if they were disconnected.

What I would actaully like is if the user has been disconnected then any attempts to save are canceled.

I attempted to modify following code to cancel the save if a user was disconnected but it fails every time even if the workbook is shared:

[How to check whether the current user has been removed from the shared workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753634/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-been-removed-from-the-shared-workbook)

I have tried creating a workbook with only the code mentioned above to determine if it was quirk from another part of the code in my main workbooks but it still fails.

Does anybody else have an idea how to determine in vba if a user was disconnected to cancel a save?

Is there an error code that I could catch that is associated with the pop up that says you are no longer connected to this work book that then asks you to save the workbook as a copy?

Would a disconnected users excel see the workbook as read only?

Comment: You will probably have to use `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) _ code here _ 
End Sub` found under ThisWorkbook. And somehow you will have to check the connectivity here and if it fails, then you should not allow the user to save.

Comment: BeforeSave event that would be :-)

Comment: Yeah I am using the before save event but I do not know what to test for connectivity there doesn't seem to be away. Maybe I could check to see if the workbook has any changes that haven't been applied I know there is a command for that

Comment: I thought I had figured it out, but I did not. Because when you check for connectivity on the beforesave event, then it is already too late. I guess you would have to use the change event, so everytime the user changes something, it will check for connectivity and notify if you are not online or not.

Comment: Hmm ok I will test this out next I am checking some other ideas I had as well if I come up with something else that also works I will share it with you for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not check during the BeforeSave event as Excel takes exclusive access of the file during this event apparently that is why any attempts to read the user list fail during this or testing for anything else.

Excel Should not allow you to save over a file if you were disconnected and you can cancel the Save As UI in the BeforeSave event to prevent a copy being made.